# Android studio crash, nothing in logcat

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, adb, logcat

I used to develop a simple price tracking application for myself with Android Studio. I paused my project for few month and got back to it recently. I noticed that my application is crashing on startup with nothing in the logcat.
I use my personal phone for development, tethered with USB, Xiaomi Android 13.

What is weird is that:

- Clear cache --> Works again
- Installing the app with android studio once again: All good
- Restarting the app after an android studio build --> Crash again with no log.

Any idea how I could troubleshoot it? Because I don't have any log and the application crash after installing it with Android Studio, I am not sure where to go with it. Could the app be wrongly packaged? But if so why would it work for the first run?

Any help is welcome :)

All the best,
Philippe

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have run **logcat** on terminal to track the errors that happen before installation.

If you connect your mobile device, then run **logcat** on terminal, then run the application again, you'll be able to see what happens before the app launches, to when it does launch, to when it crashes.

If you still can't figure out the issue, please post the logs on your question